# three.js memory leak / browser crash

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, three.js

I am building an app with a spherical panorama photo with a jpg size about 4Mb. During development I am constantly refreshing the page I am working on to see changes, as well as opening multiple other three.js example pages to get tips. When Firefox first starts up, it uses around 250MB (I have a few tabs that open by default since it keeps crashing). When I refresh the page it jumps to around 420MB, then tapers slowly back down, but usually not to where it started from. If I refresh 2 times in 15 seconds or so, it will climb to nearly 500MB.

Usually I am not paying attention to my memory usage singe I have 32GB, but when firefox gets up around 2.5GB of memory used, along with around 15% processor usage, it starts bogging down and will crash. I would understand if my scene were particularly complicated, but it isn't, for the most part it is a single spherical pano, and one additional element I am working on at the time.

Is there something I should be adding to my code to clear out buffers between refreshes?

Comment: can you share snippet of code or snapshot of profile data...?

Comment: @Stallion Here you go, it is a little more than a fiddle will allow:  http://sneakyjs.com/memoryleak/

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is a problem with TextGeometry without a solution.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/8478